# Aggregate common rows listed under columns with sample name

Tags: r, unix, aggregate

I have a tab-separated table that looks like this:

```
    sample   abundance    taxonomy
    Kapa1   4.20966 d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Oscillospirales;f__Acutalibacteraceae;g__UBA1417;s__
    Kapa1   106.368 d__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Bacteroidales;f__Bacteroidaceae;g__Bacteroides;s__Bacteroides
    Kapa1   16.9023 d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Lachnospirales;f__Lachnospiraceae;g__Clostridium_Q;s__Clostridium_Q
    Kapa1   7.39814 d__Bacteria;p__Verrucomicrobiota;c__Verrucomicrobiae;o__Verrucomicrobiales;f__Akkermansiaceae;g__Akkermansia;s__Akkermansia
    Kapa1   6.55751 d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Coriobacteriia;o__Coriobacteriales;f__Eggerthellaceae;g__Eggerthella;s__Eggerthella
    Kapa1   8.43543 d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Coriobacteriia;o__Coriobacteriales;f__Eggerthellaceae;g__Slackia_A;s__
    Kapa1   66.385  d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Lachnospirales;f__Lachnospiraceae;g__CAG-56;s__CAG-56
    Kapa2   4.90089 d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Oscillospirales;f__Acutalibacteraceae;g__UBA1417;s__
    Kapa2   4.48967 d__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Bacteroidales;f__Bacteroidaceae;g__Bacteroides;s__Bacteroides
    Kapa2   362.414 d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Lachnospirales;f__Lachnospiraceae;g__Clostridium_Q;s__Clostridium_Q
    Kapa2   179.776 d__Bacteria;p__Verrucomicrobiota;c__Verrucomicrobiae;o__Verrucomicrobiales;f__Akkermansiaceae;g__Akkermansia;s__Akkermansia
    Kapa2   185.915 d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Coriobacteriia;o__Coriobacteriales;f__Eggerthellaceae;g__Eggerthella;s__Eggerthella
    NEB1    87.3944 d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Oscillospirales;f__Acutalibacteraceae;g__UBA1417;s__
    NEB1    62.3973 d__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Bacteroidales;f__Bacteroidaceae;g__Bacteroides;s__Bacteroides
    NEB1    61.0405 d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Lachnospirales;f__Lachnospiraceae;g__Clostridium_Q;s__Clostridium_Q
    NEB1    52.5649 d__Bacteria;p__Verrucomicrobiota;c__Verrucomicrobiae;o__Verrucomicrobiales;f__Akkermansiaceae;g__Akkermansia;s__Akkermansia
    NEB2    49.7731 d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Oscillospirales;f__Acutalibacteraceae;g__UBA1417;s__
    NEB2    31.9487 d__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Bacteroidales;f__Bacteroidaceae;g__Bacteroides;s__Bacteroides
    NEB2    32.176  d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Lachnospirales;f__Lachnospiraceae;g__Clostridium_Q;s__Clostridium_Q
    NEB2    30.313  d__Bacteria;p__Verrucomicrobiota;c__Verrucomicrobiae;o__Verrucomicrobiales;f__Akkermansiaceae;g__Akkermansia;s__Akkermansia
    NEB2    31.3738 d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Coriobacteriia;o__Coriobacteriales;f__Eggerthellaceae;g__Eggerthella;s__Eggerthella
    NEB2    14.3508 d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Actinobacteria;o__Actinomycetales;f__Bifidobacteriaceae;g__Bifidobacterium;s__Bifidobacterium
```

I would like to keep the taxonomy column, but transpose the samples to colulmns, and their respective abundance for each taxonomy underneath. Note: there are taxonomies which are not found in all samples.

**Expected output**

```
taxonomy    Kapa1   Kapa2   NEB1    NEB2
d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Oscillospirales;f__Acutalibacteraceae;g__UBA1417;s__   4.20966 4.90089 87.3944 49.7731
d__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Bacteroidales;f__Bacteroidaceae;g__Bacteroides;s__Bacteroides 106.368 4.48967 62.3973 31.9487
d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Lachnospirales;f__Lachnospiraceae;g__Clostridium_Q;s__Clostridium_Q    16.9023 362.414 61.0405 32.176
d__Bacteria;p__Verrucomicrobiota;c__Verrucomicrobiae;o__Verrucomicrobiales;f__Akkermansiaceae;g__Akkermansia;s__Akkermansia 7.39814 179.776 52.5649 30.313
d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Coriobacteriia;o__Coriobacteriales;f__Eggerthellaceae;g__Eggerthella;s__Eggerthella  6.55751 185.915     31.3738
d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Coriobacteriia;o__Coriobacteriales;f__Eggerthellaceae;g__Slackia_A;s__   8.43543         
d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Lachnospirales;f__Lachnospiraceae;g__CAG-56;s__CAG-56  66.385          
d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Actinobacteria;o__Actinomycetales;f__Bifidobacteriaceae;g__Bifidobacterium;s__Bifidobacterium                14.3508
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Here's the answer:

```
library(reshape2)
test_final <- dcast(dataframe, taxonomy~sample, value.var= "abundance", fun.aggregate = sum)
```

Cheers all, and thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

A shell-based solution, using one of my favorite command line tools for working with aggregate data, [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash --header-in --filler '' crosstab 3,1 sum 2 < input.tsv
        Kapa1   Kapa2   NEB1    NEB2
d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Actinobacteria;o__Actinomycetales;f__Bifidobacteriaceae;g__Bifidobacterium;s__Bifidobacterium                                14.3508
d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Coriobacteriia;o__Coriobacteriales;f__Eggerthellaceae;g__Eggerthella;s__Eggerthella  6.55751 185.915         31.3738
d__Bacteria;p__Actinobacteriota;c__Coriobacteriia;o__Coriobacteriales;f__Eggerthellaceae;g__Slackia_A;s__       8.43543
d__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidota;c__Bacteroidia;o__Bacteroidales;f__Bacteroidaceae;g__Bacteroides;s__Bacteroides     106.368 4.48967 62.3973 31.9487
d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Lachnospirales;f__Lachnospiraceae;g__CAG-56;s__CAG-56      66.385
d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Lachnospirales;f__Lachnospiraceae;g__Clostridium_Q;s__Clostridium_Q        16.9023 362.414 61.0405 32.176
d__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes_A;c__Clostridia;o__Oscillospirales;f__Acutalibacteraceae;g__UBA1417;s__       4.20966 4.90089 87.3944 49.7731
d__Bacteria;p__Verrucomicrobiota;c__Verrucomicrobiae;o__Verrucomicrobiales;f__Akkermansiaceae;g__Akkermansia;s__Akkermansia     7.39814 179.776 52.5649 30.313
```

(Its output does lack a title for the taxonomy column, but that should be easy enough to add if needed)